# How to use ToolBar/overflow icon in Android Card ui

Tags: android, eclipse, android-toolbar, android-framelayout

I added the v7-appcompat.jar to the referenced libraries

Have the following in my Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
    ...
    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlbMenu">
    </Toolbar>
    ...
</FrameLayout>
```

I keep getting the following error: `View requires API level 21 (current min is 16): <Toolbar>`

How can I resolve the error.

I tried adding the compat toolbar and I get this error:

```
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076): Process: com.myapp, PID: 10076
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
04-08 21:17:02.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
```

Comment: `android.support.v7.widget.FrameLayout`?  Is that a thing?

Comment: I removed it. I am only using FrameLayout. typo.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: YEs i am... let me add the tag.

Comment: What version of the jar are you using?

Comment: `android-support-v7-appcompat`

Comment: What version,like 23.2.1 or 23.3, or something?

Comment: 23.1.1 is the version

Answer (score 0):

You should use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead of just Toolbar in your XML layout.

Comment: This is the first time I will be using appcompat so I am still new to it. I am using a standard FrameLayout and I want to use the Toolbar in the cardview and keep it at minSdk to 16.

Comment: Please change android.support.v7.widget.FrameLayout to just FrameLayout as it is not in the support library.

Comment: Actually I am trying to put the toolbar in a ListView inside main.xml. The ListView is populated with a RowAdapter class.